# Prerender.io Not Working in Production

Tags: angularjs, node.js, openshift, prerender

I'm trying to get my MEAN stack app set up for proper SEO, using the prerender.io middleware. Locally, everything is working great. In production, nada.The app is hosted on OpenShift. I'm using environment variables for the preRenderToken and preRenderServiceUrl (the service URL is only for dev, and points to another local node server).

In `/server/config/local.env.js`:

```
(function()
{
    'use strict';

    module.exports = Env();

    function Env()
    {
        var IEnvironmentVariables = {

            // Prerender.io
            PRERENDER_SERVICE_URL: 'http://localhost:3000/',
            PRERENDER_TOKEN: 'my prerender.io token',
        };

        return IEnvironmentVariables;
    }

})();
```

In `/server/config/environment/index.js`:

```
// Prerender.io
// I've definitely got both of these set locally and the token set on OpenShift
prerenderServiceUrl: process.env.PRERENDER_SERVICE_URL || process.env.OPENSHIFT_PRERENDER_SERVICE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000/',
prerenderToken: process.env.PRERENDER_TOKEN || process.env.OPENSHIFT_PRERENDER_TOKEN || 'prerender-token'
```

The document head contains the following `meta` tags:

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
<meta name="description" content="{{description}}">
<meta name="keywords" content="{{keywords}}">
```

These bound expressions are set on Angular's `$rootScope` like this:

```
(function()
{
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp')

    .run(['$rootScope', '$state', Run]);

    function Run($rootScope, $state)
    {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) 
        {

            // Meta tags
            $rootScope.description = $state.current.description || 'default-description';
            $rootScope.keywords = $state.current.keywords ? 
            $state.current.keywords
            .toString()
            .split(',')
            .join(' ') : 'default-keywords
        });

    }

})();
```

Finally, in each `$state` configuration, something like this:

```
(function()
{
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp')

    .config(['$stateProvider', Config]);

    function Config($stateProvider) 
    {
        $stateProvider

        .state('main', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
            controller: 'MainController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            description: 'my site description',
            keywords: ['array', 'of', 'keywords']
        });
    }

})();
```

Visiting `http://localhost:9000/?_escaped_fragment=` (or any other site pages with that query string) produces the pre-rendered page, with the proper values in the meta tags. In production, I'm able to visit `http://www.dancakes.com/?_escaped_fragment=` but the page is not pre-rendered (that is the actual site URL if you want to verify).

I've toyed around with placing the `app.use(prerender . . .)` statements in different positions, and each time I end up with something that works locally, and either partly or not at all in production.

Comment: you need underscore at end - http://www.dancakes.com/?_escaped_fragment_=

Comment: Wow. Good eye. That is the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems that you need underscore after fragment `?_escaped_fragment_=`

Comment: That was definitely it as far as getting the page to pre-render when visiting the page with that query string. Although, when I fetch as Google in Google's search console, I still only get a partial. I don't suppose you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: @MyCompassSpins, there is window.prerenderReady flag, you can set to false before angular load and set it to true after everything loaded - https://prerender.io/documentation/best-practices

Comment: Google renders a complete instead of a partial, but my Angular expressions are not being evaluated prior to rendering. This is probably another question entirely, though. Thanks for the help on this one :)

Comment: @MyCompassSpins, if you use `window.prerenderReady = true;` inside `$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){ .... });` event, it should be better, or put some more timeout to trigger it?

Comment: Huh. Putting that in `$viewContentLoaded` rather than `$stateChangeSuccess` seemed to do the trick. I'm now seeing the proper site description in Google's search results. Oddly, I still see `{{description}}` when I "Fetch As Google" in their Search Console. Weird. Thanks again!

Comment: "Fetch as Google" is known not to support the escaped fragment crawling protocol even though Googlebot does support it. That's why Fetch as Google is showing your unrendered tags but Google search results are showing the proper info from prerender.